# Best way to include multiple assets on Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I' m usign the same amount of assets in my symfony2 project. If I upgrade a plugin version, all files must be modified. So, which is the best way to add assets on twig templates using Symfony2 framework?

```
{% block javascriptCodigo %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/Bundle/js/ajaxLoadTables/ajaxLoadTables.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/Bundle/js/jquery-loadmask/jquery.loadmask.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/Bundle/js/jquery-validate/jquery.validate.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/Bundle/js/jquery-validate/localization/messages_es.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/Bundle/js/bootstrap3-dialog/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js') }}"></script>
...
```

Comment: Gonna take a look, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to use `AsseticBundle`. All is described in details in [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html).

In general, while assetic is enabled you can do something like

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {% javascripts
        '@AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/public/js/knockout.jquery-bindings.js'
        '@AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery.validate.min.js'
        '@AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery.validate.password.js'
    %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %} 
{% endblock %}
```

This will combine all your assets to one file. You can also use this for stylesheets by using `stylesheets` function. There is also easy way to add version number for your query url (for asset) which will solve browser cache issues.